# Get and order all elements from list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, list, sql-order-by

Just want to display all the int elements prodId1 from a list of objects in ascending order. Aware of the order by function but not sure the easiest way to do so.

Comment: What is `prodId1`? A property in the type that the list contains? Is the list constrained to that type, or can it contain other types of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<object> listOfObjects = { 1, "2", new object(), 3, 4, "5" };
IEnumerable<int> orderedInts = listOfObjects .OfType<int>().OrderBy(i => i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the name of the list is "list" :

```
IEnumerable<int> orderedListInts = list.OfType<int>().OrderBy(i => i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a list of objects (say of type MyRecord> with a Property ProdId1, and you want these values.

```
IList<MyRecord> list;
IEnumerable<int> ids = from item in list 
    orderby item.ProdId1 
    select item.ProdId1;
```